# python pip broken after update

Tags: python, pip

I am seeing the following error from pip on several versions of python3 that I am running:

```
...
    raise MissingSchema('Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes.')
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes.
```

It looks like something with the requests library.

And this is with pip 1.5.2 on python 3.3.4

Comment: And your proxy settings are...?

Comment: Do you think these matter? An older version of pip still works for me ... so I take that to mean that the proxy settings are not issue. But maybe there is a pip proxy config sitting somewhere that needs to get updated with the new version of pip?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing that the new version is more strict about checking that your proxy settings are valid. If you have an environment variable like `http_proxy=localhost:3128` then update it to `http_proxy=http://localhost:3128` and you should be fine again. (Ditto for `https_proxy` -- actually I guess recent versions of pip insist on using HTTPS?)

Answer (score 1):

try to use in format `pip --proxy http:proxy_name:port install packet`